# why self.editing and self.tableView.editing work same/properly?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am creating Project in which i have `FirstViewController`. In `FirstViewController` i have putted `UITableView`, and displayed all the data in proper way. On **myTableView** i putted functionality to edit `UITabelView` (*delete or insert row*)

I have **EditBtton** (`UIBarButtonItem`) on `UINavigationBar`, when i tapped it then my `UITableView` goes to in edit mode.

```
- (void) EditTable:(id)sender
{
    if(self.editing)
    {
        [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [self.tblView setEditing:NO animated:NO];

        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];

        [self myCustomMethod]; // custom method

    }
    else
    {
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self.tblView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self.tblView reloadData];
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
    }
}
```

---

**For Your Info :** All of work is properly and fine.

---

I want to only know that how to go my `UITableView` in editing mode even i have not use `UITableViewController` such like

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController // here i have UIViewController not UITableViewController
```

Then how it is possible when i write condition such i use like,

`if(self.editing)` then it check proper way, Generally it should be `if(self.tableViewObj.editing)`

> **NOTE :** I have not any error But I want to only know, how it is possible?, how it work ? and which one is best for me **if(self.editing)** or **if(self.tableViewObj.editing)**

Answer (score 2):

It's all about your UIBarButtonItem. It switches your controller to editing state.
As documentation says:

@property(nonatomic, getter=isEditing) BOOL editing
Discussion
If YES, the view controller currently allows editing; otherwise, NO.

If the view is editable and the associated navigation controller contains an edit-done button, then a Done button is displayed; otherwise, an Edit button is displayed. Clicking either button toggles the state of this property. Add an edit-done button by setting the custom left or right view of the navigation item to the value returned by the editButtonItem method. Set the editing property to the initial state of your view. Use the setEditing:animated: method as an action method to animate the transition of this state if the view is already displayed.